# Picasso Singleton Usage

Tags: android, singleton, picasso

I am using Picasso in my app.

First, I only use the format below:

```
Picasso.with(context)....into(imgView);
```

This way I assume I use Picasso as a singleton. Do I?

Second, I want to use `setIndicatorsEnabled`. However it cannot be added to the format above since it is not a static method. Is there any way to use this function in the format above?

Third, if I need to create a custom instance using `Picasso.Builder(...).build()` in order to use `setIndicatorsEnabled`, what is the best way to achieve singleton usage across the activities of the app?

Comment: `Do I?` : see https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java#L591 (yes)

Comment: `setIndicatorsEnabled` : `with` returns an instance. call `setIndicatorsEnabled` on that instance

Comment: The API methods for Picasso is changed, Please use the latest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you assume Picasso is a singleton instance when you use Picasso.with(context)....

to use set indicators enabled

```
Picasso mPicasso = Picasso.with(context);
mPicasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
mPicasso....load().into(imageView);
```

if you use the builder you should create your own singleton to hold your instance of Picasso and clean it up when your done. Do not use builder every time that you use picasso because it creates a new instance. I believe that Picasso.with(context) just takes your context and calls getApplicationContext and stores a singleton instance of picasso with the application context.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good way to implement a singleton Picasso class

```
public class ImageHandler {

    private static Picasso instance;

    public static Picasso getSharedInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Picasso.Builder(context).executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).memoryCache(Cache.NONE).indicatorsEnabled(true).build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And then an implementation of it in code would be as follows:

```
    ImageHandler.getSharedInstance(getApplicationContext()).load(imString).skipMemoryCache().resize(width, height).into(image, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

Note that you don't have to implement the callbacks if not necessary

Comment: If you put that return statement outside your if-else clause and remove the duplicate, your code will be a lot cleaner

Answer (score 1):

The current method seems to be to use `setSingletonInstance`

Run this in you application create:

```
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(Picasso.Builder(context).build()
```